# Is this an interesting generalization of the notion of an open set?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, soft-question

Let $X$ denote a topological space. Some subsets $A \subseteq X$ might have the property that $\partial A = \partial(\mathrm{int}\,A).$ This is certainly true if $A$ is open (since open implies $\mathrm{int}\,A = A$).

Thus, the property that $\partial A = \partial(\mathrm{int}\,A)$ can be viewed as a generalization of "open." Edit: Lets call this property "weakly open."

Other $A$'s might have the property that $\partial A = \partial(\mathrm{cl}\,A)$. Lets call this "weakly closed."

So any given $A \subseteq X$ may be weakly open only, weakly closed only, it may be have both properties, or neither.

Is there anything interesting that can be said about such $A$'s? Reference, anyone?

Edit: As Arthur points out in his answer, the arbitrary union of weakly open sets is weakly open. Thus, we can take the "weak interior" of a subset $B$, defined as the union of the set of all weakly open $A$ such that $A \subseteq B$. The weak interior will always be a **superset** of the usual interior.

Comment: I would have called this "weakly open". Because usually, things that are "strongly P" are a subset of things that are "P".

Comment: Oh yeah............... (how embarrassing!)

Comment: Now that you're going with "weakly open", in the Edit referring to Arthur's answer, maybe it should say arbitrary unions of weakly open sets are weakly open (the term "strongly open" having been abandoned).

Comment: Yes I think i fixed that... do you still see the term "strongly open" anywhere?

Comment: OK now. Weakly open is an interesting notion in my opinion.

Comment: There seems to be an endless number of minor variations on topological notions in the literature, so if you're *really interested* in the idea you defined, you will want to look around some. Examples, googled at random: Khalaf/Ameen, [$sc$-*open sets and* $sc$-*continuity in topological spaces*](http://www.i-asr.com/jarpm/uploadsend/380vol_2_issue_3_jarpm_pp_87-101.pdf) (2010); Ekici, [*On pre*-$I$-*open sets, semi*-$I$-*open sets and* $b$-$I$-*open sets in ideal topological spaces*](http://www.emis.de/journals/AUA/acta30/Paper28-Acta30-2012.pdf) (2012).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $\newcommand{\Int}{\mathrm{Int}}A \subseteq X$ we have $\partial A = \overline{A} \setminus \Int (A)$, so in particular $$\partial ( \Int ( A ) ) = \overline{ \Int (A) } \setminus \Int ( \Int ( A ) ) = \overline{ \Int (A) } \setminus \Int ( A ).$$ As $\Int ( A ) \subseteq \overline{ \Int (A) } \subseteq \overline{A}$ your condition is equivalent to $\overline{ \Int ( A ) } = \overline{A}$.

A couple of notes:

1. Regular closed sets ($A = \overline{ \Int ( A ) }$) are weakly open.
2. Weak openness is not necessarily closed under finite intersections (*e.g.*, in $\mathbb R$ both $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ are regular closed sets).
3. Weak openness is closed under finite unions (if $A$ and $B$ satisfy this condition, then $\overline{ A \cup B } = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} = \overline{ \Int (A) } \cup \overline{ \Int(B) } = \overline{ \Int (A) \cup \Int (B) } \subseteq \overline{ \Int ( A \cup B ) } \subseteq \overline{ A \cup B }$.)
4. Weak openness is even closed under arbitrary unions

   Given a family $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$ of weakly open sets, let $x \in \overline{ \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i }$ and let $U$ be an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $x$.  As $U \cap \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \neq \emptyset$ there is an $i \in I$ such that $U \cap A_i \neq \emptyset$.  Clearly $A_i \subseteq \overline{ A_ i} = \overline{ \Int ( A_i ) }$ and so $\emptyset \neq U \cap \Int ( A_i ) \subseteq U \cap \Int ( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i )$.  Thus $x \in \overline{ \Int ( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i ) }$.
5. Note that if we define $A \subseteq X$ to be *weakly closed* iff $X \setminus A$ is weakly open it follows that $A$ is weakly closed iff $\Int ( A ) = \Int ( \overline{A} )$, which is the natural dual to weak openness.

---

In my opinion, due to (2) this is a fairly poor generalisation of openness (we generally like our set-structures to be closed under finite unions and intersections).  I was actually looking for counterexample to (4) for a while, and was a bit surprised to see that this holds.  At least with this you can unproblematically define the "*weak interior*" of a set to be the largest weakly open subset of that set.

I suspect (though have not yet been able to prove) that you can have two non-homeomorphic topologies on a set for which the families of weakly open sets coincide.  This would *almost* seem to put a nail in the coffin of this notion, but that would be a rash judgement: note that you can have non-homeomorphic topologies on a set for which the families of Borel sets coincide, and no-one questions the importance of Borel sets.

Comment: This is a good answer! Which terminology do you prefer, "strongly open" or "boundary-open"? I'll modify my question according to your opinion. Edit: I prefer "strongly open" because "boundary-open" sounds like it is asserting that the set has an open boundary.

Comment: @user18921: I'll change my answer to use "strongly open".

Comment: Turns out I made a HUGE mistake. They should really be called "weakly open," because "a weakly open subset of $X$ needn't be open." (How embarrassing!)